# How to get the "belongs_to" association with Ecto in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a Post and Comment model.  One post has many comments and one comment belongs to a post.

When showing an individual comment, how can I access the post that it belongs to?

i.e. in Ruby on Rails you could do:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@post = @comment.post
```

How could I achieve this using the Phoenix Elixir framework?  I believe I have my model associations set up properly but I am confused on how to actually get this query in either the view or the controller.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you read the [Ecto.Schema](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html) docs then you will see how to create a [belongs_to/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3) association.

```
defmodule MyApp.Comment do
  use MyApp.Model

  schema "comments" do
    belongs_to :post, MyApp.Post
  end
end
```

With the association set up you can use [Repo.preload/2](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/2) to fetch the assocation.

```
Repo.preload(comment, :post).post
```

You can also preload in a query if you have not fetched the resource with [Ecto.Query.preload/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3)